# VBA to Select All Checkboxes FormControl

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a code to select/deselect all checkboxes with one "master" checkbox. This code is for OLEObjects/Active X controls, and im having a hard time rewriting it to work with Form Controls checkboxes. Any idea?

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 39
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim v As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        v = .CheckBoxes(1).Value
        n = .CheckBoxes.Count
        For i = 2 To n
            .CheckBoxes(i) = v
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
Sub Ia_Click()

    For i = 41 To 78
         ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(i).Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(40).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```